# CodeIgniter benchmarking with Smarty

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, smarty

I've connected Smarty to CodeIgniter and now of course i cant use {memory_used} and {elapsed_time}, but i want to know how i can output this information to my webpage now?

Comment: The one who downvoted this question didn't really understand the problem. It really is an issue with how CodeIgniter handles these functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Benchmark class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/benchmark.html)

```
$this->benchmark->elapsed_time()
$this->benchmark->memory_usage()
```

They do return their mustached values that are parsed by output class later, so if you use Smarty, you can basically use the raw functions CodeIgniter uses itself.

```
$memory = ( ! function_exists('memory_get_usage')) ? '0' : round(memory_get_usage()/1024/1024, 2).'MB';
global $BM; // needed only for elapsed_time
$elapsed_time = $BM->elapsed_time('total_execution_time_start', 'total_execution_time_end');
```

Note it is really a workaround and there should be better ways to do it.

Comment: Yea, tried this, **$this->tpl->assign('message', $this->benchmark->elapsed_time());**, but this just outputs  line **{elapsed_time}**
if i write like this **{$this->benchmark->memory_usage()}** in html, i get **Call to a member function memory_usage() on a non-objec**

Answer (score 1):

Just read the documentation. Its right there.

`$this->benchmark->elapsed_time()` and `$this->benchmark->memory_usage()`

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt do "global $BM" inside a smarty template, so in my controller constructor I did:

```
global $BM;
$this->smarty->assign("BM", $BM);
```

and then in my template:

```
{$BM->elapsed_time()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{literal}{elapsed_time}{/literal}
```

Tested and works.